# Copy images from SQL image field to Azure Blob Storage as blob blocks

Tags: ssis, database-migration, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have a SQL table where I have stored a lot of images, something with the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentsContent](
    [BlobName] [varchar](33) NULL,
    [Content] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I need to copy all images from database to Azure Blobs. The problem is that there are 3TB of images, so a script that will read them one by one (from SQL) and copy to Azure is not the desired solution.

I've tried with **SSIS** and **Data Factory**, but both are creating only one file with all information, not one file for each row how I need (or at lest in the way I did).

There is any tool that can do in a decent time? Or there is any way to used SSIS or Data Factory for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 activities in Azure data factory to achieve it:

1. use a lookup activity to get the count of rows
2. use foreach activity with the rowcount as input and since each row is independent ,you can keep parallel execution enabled.

Within foreach,use copy activity with source as SQL with filter condition to rownumber and destination as blob.

This would generate individual files for each row and would occur parallely

Comment: Thank you for your solution. For go throw each row and take the information, it's working.

Comment: @Irina
Great to know that it was helpful.
Can you please mark it as answer so that it would be beneficial for the community as well

Comment: @Nadan, is not 10% finished; I need to figure out how the files will be copied; right now just parse the records. SQL as a source doesn't work having Azure Blob as destination; should add something else I think

Comment: @Irina:
you can have SQL as a source in ADF and Storage as Sink to copy files

Comment: @Nadan, yes, as source I have a SQL dataset with the following query as example: SELECT TOP 1  Content
FROM DocumentsContent and as Sink the Azure Blob; If as source I use an Azure Blob dataset, it's working (because both source and destinations are binary data types); so I imagine for SQL need a formatting or another component to link

Comment: The erros is: "Source must be binary when sink is binary dataset."

Answer (score 0):

Other Ideas:

Option 1)

- SSIS Data Flow Task - "[Export Column](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2693/export-images-from-a-sql-server-table-to-a-folder-with-ssis/)" to Local Disk
- Use Filezilla Pro (or eqivalent) to Multithread Transfer to Azure

Option 2)

- Mount Azure Blob via NFS3.0
- SSIS Data Flow Task - "Export Column" to Mounted Disk

Split workload for parallel execution

```
WHERE CHECKSUM([BlobName]) % 5 = 0
WHERE CHECKSUM([BlobName]) % 5 = 1
WHERE CHECKSUM([BlobName]) % 5 = 2
WHERE CHECKSUM([BlobName]) % 5 = 3
WHERE CHECKSUM([BlobName]) % 5 = 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I wanted to avoid copying of files to a local disk